# None of the JavaScript Objects function or display on browser

Tags: javascript, html, object

I'm new to JavaScript. I'm trying to play a bit with Objects, like creating them and displaying them, etc. For some reason, nothing is showing up in any browser I try on: FireFox, Google Chrome, and the beloved Internet Explorer. I'm pretty sure I typed it in correct, along with connecting the external document to my page. I've tried to put it in both the 'head' tag and the 'body' tag. I've also assigned the ID to a 'p' tag correctly. Other functions of code work perfectly, it's anything Object related that doesn't work. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? May I have some help? Thank you.

**JavaScript:**

```
function person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;
}

var myFather = new person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
var myMother = new person("Sally", "Rally", 48, "green");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"My father is " + myFather.age + ". My mother is " + myMother.age;
```

Comment: What is not working? http://jsfiddle.net/M7MMs/ (Make sure the code is executed at page load)

Comment: Following @Derek朕會功夫's suggestion, it may help to move the script tag to the bottom of the body.

Comment: The whole function is not being displayed when called. I have a 'p' tag that has the id 'demo' that is supposed to display what is called in the document at the bottom of the code. It seems to work on that link, but for some reason, it won't show in my own HTML page. This is my HTML - just within the link. It works on there, but not on the actual page I've created. http://jsfiddle.net/SpottedFire/sMzBv/

Comment: @SpottedFire - By looking at your fiddle, it seems like you are executing your code before the content is loaded. As I said, make sure the page is loaded before doing anything. (Wrap your code with `$(function(){})` since I see you are using jQuery)

Comment: @SpottedFire - Also are you following this [W3Schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_create_object3)? If yes, then you shouldn't really be using jQuery until you have mastered the basics imo.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I am using W3Schools for help, this is the place I'm getting it from: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_create_object2  I didn't know I'm using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One rule that you can always follow is to keep your JavaScript code at the bottom of page, just before body tag closes. Like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function person(first, last, age, eye) {
        this.firstName = first;
        this.lastName = last;
        this.age = age;
        this.eyeColor = eye;
    }

    var myFather = new person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
    var myMother = new person("Sally", "Rally", 48, "green");

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
     "My father is " + myFather.age + ". My mother is " + myMother.age;
</script>
</body>
```

and everything will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you. It's working now. Does the script have to be just at the end of the body tag to work?

Comment: In short, yes. To understand why we need it at the bottom of the page is to understand way DOM is rendered by browser. DOM is rendered in top down approach, starting from `<HTML>` tag and when elements appear in that top down fashion browser keeps them adding to DOM. Now, when browser encounters a `<script>` tag, then it stops further parsing of HTML and it starts executing JavaScript code. So, now consider this, in this JavaScript code we are trying to get an HTML element that is not yet in DOM because JavaScript code is executed before browser knows that there is an element like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
function person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;
}

var myFather = new person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
var myMother = new person("Sally", "Rally", 48, "green");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"My father is " + myFather.age + ". My mother is " + myMother.age;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">
<p id = "demo">Hello World!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

check this out, its working, just call the function on `onload` or what event you want it to show.

This is a [list](http://help.dottoro.com/larrqqck.php) of events you can choose from.

Comment: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"` is better than `onload` ;)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, thanks for that. But showing and teaching a newbie here in javascript. :)

Comment: Only "Hello World!" is showing up on my browser. Both FireFox, Chrome, and IE :(

Comment: @SpottedFire  this should be like `<p = "demo">Hello World!</p>` , see formatted answer

Comment: @SpottedFire What the heck is `<p = "demo">`? Do you mean `<p id= "demo">`?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I wasn't the one who typed in that line of code. I put <p id = "demo">

Comment: @SpottedFire - Oh sorry I mean @­Niang.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 `id` element omitted,sorry for that.

Comment: @SpottedFire `<p id = "demo">Hello World!</p>` is right now,sorry for typo error

Answer (score 0):

Its actually working code. you just need to give a div with **id=demo** in your page body section so that you get the output because you displaying your result in div id="demo".

Try this as your code

```
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="demo"> </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var myFather = new person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
 var myMother = new person("Sally", "Rally", 48, "green");

 function person(first, last, age, eye) {
   this.firstName = first;
   this.lastName = last;
   this.age = age;
   this.eyeColor = eye;
 }

 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="My father is " + myFather.age + ". My mother is " + myMother.age;
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

look this http://jsfiddle.net/23ck7